# Fetching data from two API to merge them in one table

Tags: javascript, promise

First of all,

you can see below, my working program to fetch Data from two different APIs in two different tables.

First table contains the data from an API : `{Cycle, Delegated Stack, Share, expected payment}`
The second one gets the data from another API to get : `{the cycle, paid reward}`
https://codepen.io/alexand92162579/pen/arJqmv?editors=1010

The second Code pen is the same thing but I want to merge the two tables according to the value of the cycle:
https://codepen.io/alexand92162579/pen/OGdjLJ?editors=1011

According to what I read online, I need to use Promises. I have tried this multiple times but never succeeded to make it work !

To try it, enter the Key `KT19www5fiQNAiqTWrugTVLm9FB3th5DzH54` in the inputbox.

I will make a donation of 30xtz if someone helps me on this one.

```
  // Fonction to fetch the data for every cycle on the first API
  // Data Recolted (Cycle, Balance, Share, Expected Reward, Fee, Status)
  // Try to merge with the second table according to the value of cycle
  // // KT19www5fiQNAiqTWrugTVLm9FB3th5DzH54 */

 function calculate2() {
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { table: "cycle", limit: 10 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var KT1 = $('#KT1').val();
console.log(KT1);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

  Qfee = 0.08;

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    txt += "<table><tr bgcolor=#000000 color=White>"
    txt += "<th>Cycle</th>"
    txt += "<th>Balance</th>"
    txt += "<th>Share</th>"
    txt += "<th>Reward</th>"
    txt += "<th>Fee</th>"
    txt += "<th>Status</th>"
    txt += "</tr>"

          for (x in myObj) {
            cycle = myObj[x].cycle;
            balance = myObj[x].balance/1000000;
            TotalReward = myObj[x].rewards/1000000;
            status = myObj[x].status.status;
            stakingBalance = myObj[x].staking_balance/1000000;
            Share = balance/stakingBalance*100;
            Fee = Share*TotalReward*Qfee/100;
            DelegatorReward = Share*TotalReward/100 - Fee;

            txt += "<tr>";
            txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + cycle + "</td>";
            txt += "<td width=25% align=center>" + Math.round(balance*100)/100 + "</td>";
            txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + Math.round(Share*10)/10 + " %" + "</td>";
            txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + Math.round(DelegatorReward*100)/100 + "</td>";
            txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + Math.round(Qfee*1000)/10 + " %"  + "</td>";
            txt += "<td width=30% align=left>" + status + "</td>";
            txt += "</tr>";


    }
        txt += "</table>";    
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
      }
  };
xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/" + KT1, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}

  /*Fonction to fetch the data for every cycle on the second API
  // Data Recolted (Cycle, Payment)
  // Try to merge with the first table according to the value of cycle
  // // KT19www5fiQNAiqTWrugTVLm9FB3th5DzH54*/
  function calculate3() {
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
    obj = { table: "cycle", limit: 10 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var KT1 = $('#KT1').val();
    //console.log(KT1);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        txt += "<table><tr bgcolor=#000000 color=White>"
        //txt += "<th>Block</th>"
        txt += "<th>Cycle</th>"
        txt += "<th>Paid</th>"
        txt += "</tr>"

//If one transaction has been done for the cycle get from the API request 1 then I put the data on the last column of the table
         for (var x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
                if (KT1 == myObj[x].type.operations[0].destination.tz) {
                  console.log("Get one");
                  Block = myObj[x].type.operations[0].op_level;
                  console.log(Block);
                  PaiementCycle = Math.round(Block/4096);
                  PaiementCycle = PaiementCycle - 6;
                  console.log(PaiementCycle);
                  Paid = myObj[x].type.operations[0].amount/1000000;
                  console.log(Paid);
                txt += "<tr>";
                //txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + Block + "</td>";
                txt += "<td width=10% align=center>" + PaiementCycle + "</td>";
                txt += "<td width=25% align=center>" + Paid + "</td>";
                txt += "</tr>";
                  console.log(txt);
                } else {
                 //console.log("Next");
                }

              }
        txt += "</table>";    
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = txt;
        return txt;
console.log("ici :" + xmlhttp);

      }
  };

xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operations/tz1XynULiFpVVguYbYeopHTkLZFzapvhZQxs?type=Transaction&number=100", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}


        $(function () {
            /*when #tezos input loses focus, as per original question*/
            $('#KT1').blur(function () {
              calculate3();
               calculate2();
              console.log(back)
            });
            $('#KT1').change(function () {
                calculate3();
              calculate2();
            });
            $('#KT1').on(function () {
                calculate3();
              calculate2();
            });
            $('#KT1').keyup(function () {
                calculate3();
              calculate2();

            });
            $('#KT1').keydown(function () {
                calculate3();              
              calculate2();
            });
        });


</script>
```

Comment: What is *"30xtz"*?

Comment: You are making an http2 request on every  iteration on first loop and i think which is  a bad approach to do this. You must store your cycle value in an array and then iterate that array to match in the 2nd http request. and then update your 'Paid' collumn.

Comment: Tezos ! Its a cryptocurrency like Ethereum or Bitcoin !

Answer (score 0):

not tested - but i think it might help - i also tried to reduce function sizes for readability ;)

```js
function getAndLogKT1(){

    var KT1 = document.querySelector('#KT1')
    console.log(KT1 && KT1.textContent)
    return KT1 && KT1.textContent
}
function firstApiReadystatechange(){

    
}
function createTable(){

    return document.createElement('table');
}

function addTableHeader(table, keys){

    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){

        var th = document.createElement('th')
        var text = document.createTextNode(keys[i])
        th.appendChild(text)
        tr.appendChild(th)
    }
    thead.appendChild(tr)
    table.appendChild(thead)
}


function addRowToTableBody(table, rowItems){

    var body = table.querySelector('tbody')
    if(!body){

        body = document.createElement('tbody')
        table.appendChild(body)
    }
    var tr = document.createElement('tr')
    for(var i = 0; i < rowItems.length; i++){

        var td = document.createElement('td')
        var text = document.createTextNode(rowItems[i])
        td.appendChild(text)
        tr.appendChild(td)
    }
    body.appendChild(tr)
}

function getDbParam(dbParmaObj){

    return JSON.stringify(dbParmaObj)
}
function sendRequestFirstApi(xmlhttp, KT1, dbParam){

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/delegator_rewards_with_details/" + KT1, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
function fetchDataForEveryCycleOnFirstApi(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    
            var Qfee = 0.08;
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
    
                try {
                    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

                    resolve(responseObj)
                } catch {

                    reject({err: "json parse error"})
                }
            }
        }    
        sendRequestFirstApi(xmlhttp, getAndLogKT1(), getDbParam({table: "cycle", limit: 10}))
    })
}
function sendRequestSecondApi(xmlhttp, dbParam){
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operations/tz1XynULiFpVVguYbYeopHTkLZFzapvhZQxs?type=Transaction&number=100", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
}
function fetchDataForEveryCycleOnSecondApi(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    
            var Qfee = 0.08;
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
    
                try {
                    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText)

                    resolve(responseObj)
                } catch {

                    reject({err: "json parse error"})
                }
            }
        }    
        sendRequestSecondApi(xmlhttp, getDbParam({table: "cycle", limit: 10}))
    })
}
function parseObjectCycleHashed(respObject){

    var retObj = {}
    for(var x in respObject){

        retObj[respObject[x]['cycle']] = respObject[x]
    }
    return retObj
}
function mergeCycleHashedResponseObjects(a,b){

    let cyclesA = Object.keys(a)
    
    var retObj = Object.assign({}, b)
    for(var i = 0; i < cyclesA.length; i++){

        Object.assign(retObj, {[cyclesA[i]]: a[cyclesA[i]] })
    }
    return retObj
}
function addToDOM(element, querySelector){

    var el = document.querySelector(querySelector)
    el && el.appendChild(element)
}
async function main(){

    var responseObjApiOne = await fetchDataForEveryCycleOnFirstApi();
    var responseObjApiTwo = await fetchDataForEveryCycleOnSecondApi();
    var responseObjApiOneCycleBased = parseObjectCycleHashed(responseObjApiOne);
    var responseObjApiTowCycleBased = parseObjectCycleHashed(responseObjApiTwo);
    var mergedObject = mergeCycleHashedResponseObjects(responseObjApiOneCycleBased, responseObjApiTowCycleBased)
    var table = createTable()
    const headerKeys = [
        "Cycle",
        "Balance",
        "Share",
        "Reward",
        "Fee",
        "Status",
        "Paid"
    ]
    addTableHeader(table, headerKeys)
    for(var cycle in mergedObject){

        addRowToTableBody(table, headerKeys.map(columnTitle => {

            return mergedObject[cycle][columnTitle]
        }))
    }

    addToDOM(table, "dmeo2")
}
```